# Golang Delve: Drop into debugger when unit test fails

Tags: unit-testing, go, delve

I'm trying to have Delve drop into a debugger when a test from the `testing` package fails. How can I do this?

For reference, I'm looking for functionality similar to nose, pytest, or other python testing packages. [Using nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/debug.html), I can do

```
nosetests test_things.py --pdb
```

which would let me trop into a debugger when any unit tests fail.

Comment: It looks like there is a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380530/debugging-tests-with-delve) with some details.