# Debugging tests with delve

Tags: debugging, go, delve

I'm using **"go test -v**" to run bunch of unit tests. I'd like to debug them using delve. When I try to run debugger, I get an **"Can not debug non-main package"** error. So, how can I debug unit tests using delve debugger ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`dlv test`](https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_test.md):

```
$ dlv test -- -test.v
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) continue
=== RUN   TestReadFileError
--- PASS: TestReadFileError (0.00s)
=== RUN   TestReadFile
--- PASS: TestReadFile (0.00s)
[..]
PASS
Process 8014 has exited with status 0
(dlv) quit
Process 8014 has exited with status 0
```

You can also pass `-test.run` to select tests to run (just like `go test -run`).

Internally, this is the same as Flimzy's answer (it compiles the test binary with `go test -c`), but more streamlined and won't leave .test files for you to clean up.

Comment: Where is `-test.run` documented? It's not in https://github.com/derekparker/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_test.md

Comment: It's a flag for the binary compiled with `go test`, not delve @jcollum

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with delve, but if it can work on a compiled binary, just compile your tests using the `-c` flag:

```
    -c
        Compile the test binary to pkg.test but do not run it
        (where pkg is the last element of the package's import path).
        The file name can be changed with the -o flag.
```

Then run delve on the output.

Comment: I got this to work dlv exec ./pkg.test -- -gocheck.f  TestLoadImage but Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) step
Stopped at: 0x7fe7886b2090
=>   1: no source available
Command failed: no source for PC 0x7fe7886b2090  How do you indicate where the source code should be?